# save sorted elements in text file c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have **bubble sort** program that sort array in **ascending**.

How can I save in TEXT FILE the sorted elements, and put commas (,) every other number ex.(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3,4) ?

And inside the text file is the sorted elements. (-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int compare (int, int);
void sort(int[], const int);
int compare(int x, int y){
    return(x > y);
}
void swap(int *x, int *y){
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
void display(int array[], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << array[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void sort(int table[], const int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
            if(compare(table[j],table[j+1]))
                swap(&table[j],&table[j+1]);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int quantity;
    int* tab;
    ofstream outfile;
    cout<<"Enter number of element: ";
    cin>>quantity;
    tab = new int [quantity];
    cout<<"Element:\n\n"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i < quantity; i++){
        int x = i;
        cout<<"#"<<++x<<":";
        cin>>tab[i];
    }
    sort(tab, quantity);
    cout<<"The Sorted Elements are: ";

    display(tab, quantity);
    cout<<endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Posting all of your code was unnecessary. You could simply ask how to save an array of `int` to file, and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: That indentation... please fix it

Comment: A stream is a stream is a stream. All text streams work just the same, no matter if it's `std::cout` or some file stream.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cout`, use a `filestream` that [writes to a file](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int compare(int, int);
void sort(int[], const int);
int compare(int x, int y){
    return(x > y);
}
void swap(int *x, int *y){
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
void display(int array[], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void writeToFile(int array[], int n){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        myfile << array[i];
        if (i != n - 1){
            myfile << ", ";
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
void sort(int table[], const int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (compare(table[j], table[j + 1]))
                swap(&table[j], &table[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int quantity;
    int* tab;
    ofstream outfile;
    cout << "Enter number of element: ";
    cin >> quantity;
    tab = new int[quantity];
    cout << "Element:\n\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++){
        int x = i;
        cout << "#" << ++x << ":";
        cin >> tab[i];
    }
    sort(tab, quantity);
    cout << "The Sorted Elements are: ";

    display(tab, quantity);
    writeToFile(tab, quantity);
    cout << endl;
    getchar();
    getchar();
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have defined function to write to file:

```
void writeToFile(int array[], int n){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        myfile << array[i];
        if (i != n - 1){
            myfile << ", ";
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

This function taken in the array and array size, and then separates successive elements with a `,` if the element is not the last element.

In `main()`, i have called it just like your `display()` function like so:

```
writeToFile(tab, quantity);
```